# Abelian Group of order $2^l$ has only one element of order $2$, then this group is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

My take was to assume $G$ not to be cyclic, take a nontrivial element $g\in G$ and another element $h\in G\setminus\langle g\rangle$ and show that $g^{{\rm ord}(g)/2}$ and $h^{{\rm ord}(h)/2}$ are elements of order $2$.

I cannot exclude the possibility that they're the same element. Am I on the wrong track here?

Edit: Yes, assumption is that the group is abelian.

Comment: Maybe you are assuming that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not assume that $G$ is abelian, then this is false: the group $Q_8$ has order $8$, but only one element of order $2$ and it is not cyclic.

However, there aren't many possibilities: every finite $p$-group with a unique subgroup of order $p$ is either cyclic of [generalised quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group#Generalized_quaternion_group).

In particular then if $G$ is abelian and as above then it is also cyclic. You can prove this directly: from the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, any abelian group decomposes into a direct product of cyclic groups, so $G=C_{n_1} \times \dots \times C_{n_k}$. From Lagrange's theorem, each $n_i$ is a power of $2$. Now any cyclic group of order a power of $2$ contains a unique element of order $2$, so each $C_{n_i}$ contains an element of order $2$. Then the only possibility is that $k=1$, so $G=C_{n_1}$ is cyclic.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I stated the question incompletely. Sorry.

Comment: I fixed the answer to cover both questions